# Sound recording (waveInOpen) does not work well in Windows 11 Home

Tags: c++, audio, recording

I have programmed an application in C++ for sound recording and recognition. For recording I use the waveInOpen function. In Windows 10 and Windows 11 Pro the application works well. In Windows 11 Home, however, the sound recording only works if the Sound settings (operation system window) is open. I have tried this on several PCs with the same result described above. Does anyone know how to configure the OS to make the app work without opening the Sound settings system window?

Comment: What happens when it doesn't work? No sound? Some error? (message/details?)

Comment: Only no sound is recorded and no errors appear.